# Access 2007 VBA Report email per company

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a suppliers' report about 150 pages in access 2007. Each report has address, emails contact person,  phone number, products and name of company per page. Once a month I have to send an email to the suppliers to confirm changes of contact person address, phone number and products.

I want to send that particular report to that particular email not the whole report.
I want this to be automated.

I have written code in VBA after research on the net and still not working. I am getting Too many parameters. Expected 1. Error.

Below is code for my form with a Send Report button.

```
Dim strSql As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMsgBody As String
strSql = "SELECT DISTINCT Name, EMail FROM [Suppliers and Products]"

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql)

'loop through the recordset

 Do While Not rst.EOF
    ' grab email string

    strEmail = rst.Fields("EMail")

    ' grab name
    strName = rst.Fields("Name")

    Call fnUserID(rst.Fields("EMail"))

    'send the pdf of the report to curent supplier
    On Error Resume Next

    strSubject = "September 2012 Supplier's Listing"
    strMsgBody = "2008 Procedure Review Attached"
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Suppliers Confirmation forms", acFormatHTML, strEmail, , , strSubject, strMsgBody, False

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, "Delivery Failure to the following email address: " & strEmail
    End If

    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    ' move and loop
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

' clean up
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

PROC_Exit:
Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume PROC_Exit
```

I have a module with the following code

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function fnUserID(Optional Somevalue As Variant = Null, Optional reset As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Static EMail As Variant
    If reset Or IsEmpty(EMail) Then EMail = Null
    If Not IsNull(Somevalue) Then EMail = Somevalue

    fnUserID = EMail
End Function

Public Function SendReportByEmail(strReportName As String, strEmail As String)
    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

    Dim strRecipient As String
    Dim strSubject As String
    Dim strMessageBody As String
    'set the email variables
    strRecipients = strEmail
    strSubject = Reports(strReportName).Caption
    strMessageBody = "May 2012 Suppliers' List "

    ' send report as HTML
    DoCmd.SendObjectac acSendReport, strReportName, acFormatHTML, strRecipients, , , strSubject,    strMessageBody, False
    SendReportByEmail = True

    PROC_Exit:
    Exit Function
    Proc Err:

    SendReportByEmail = False

    If Err.Number = 2501 Then
        Call MsgBox("The email was not sent for " & strEmail & ".", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton1, "User Cancelled Operation")
        Else: MsgBox Err.Description
    End If
    Resume PROC_Exit

End Function
```

The query which is report is getting its data has the following SQL.

```
SELECT Names.Name, Names.Phys_Address, 
       Names.Telephones, Names.Fax, Names.EMail, 
       Names.Web, Names.Caption AS Expr1, [Products by Category].CatName, 
       [Products by Category].ProdName
FROM [Names] 
INNER JOIN [Products by Category] 
ON Names.SuppID=[Products by Category].SupID
WHERE ((Names.EMail = fnUserID()) or (fnUserID() Is Null));
```

Please help as I am stuck to where I am going wrong.

Comment: You are using Name as a field name, this is a very bad idea. It is a [reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) and will cause more and more problems as you go along. Always indent your code. Avoid `On error Resume Next`, it masks problems and is almost never a good idea.

Comment: Does your report open on its own? What line gives the error? Comment out your error coding so you get a line that fails.

Comment: The database was already created. One of the field is Name. The report doesn't open on its. i created it and it has just a send button and the code i posted.

Comment: Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql) Error 3601: Too few parameters.Expected 1.

Comment: If you mean this line `SELECT DISTINCT Name, EMail FROM [Suppliers and Products]`, paste it into SQL view of the query design window and then switch to design view and see what it says.

Comment: @Remou Its says Undefined function 'fnUserID' in expression.

Comment: It is a pretty strange function and completely unnecessary I reckon. Where did you put it? If you want a query to refer to a function, you must put it in an ordinary module, not in a form or report module. The error also suggests that [Suppliers and Products] is a query, but I do not see why you need to select from a query just to get a list of suppliers.

Comment: @Remou. The database was designed that way. Suppliers and Products is a query.  The function is in the ordinary module. it has to filter a page for the particular email to send to.

Comment: There is a report which needs to be filtered. It has about 145 pages. this report has details for suppliers. each has to be sent to them. not the whole report. the function is meant to filter and need help there.

Comment: Is the last SQL the sql from the query [Suppliers and Products]? If it is, you can see than fnUserID will always be null. To test that fnUserID exists as far as your application is concerned, type `?fnUserID()` into the immediate window (go to the code window and type ctrl+G to get the immediate window)

Comment: It seems to me that you are going about this all the wrong way. I will answer with a few notes that you can build on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes.

```
On Error GoTo PROC_ERR

Dim qdf As QueryDef
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSubject As String
Dim strMsgBody As String

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT [Name], EMail, SuppID FROM Names " _
       & "INNER JOIN [Products by Category] " _
       & "ON Names.SuppID=[Products by Category].SupID "

Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSql)

qrySQL = "SELECT Names.Name, Names.Phys_Address, " _
       & "Names.Telephones, Names.Fax, Names.EMail, " _
       & "Names.Web, Names.Caption AS Expr1, " _
       & "[Products by Category].CatName, " _
       & "[Products by Category].ProdName " _
       & "FROM [Names] " _
       & "INNER JOIN [Products by Category] " _
       & "ON Names.SuppID=[Products by Category].SupID "

'loop through the recordset

 Do While Not rst.EOF
    ' grab email string

    strEmail = rst.Fields("EMail")

    ' grab name
    strName = rst.Fields("Name")

    ' You should check that the email is not null
    Call fnUserID(rst.Fields("EMail"))

    'send the pdf of the report to curent supplier
    'On Error Resume Next

    'The query that the report uses
    Set qdf = CurrentDB.QueryDefs("Suppliers and Products")
    qdf.SQL = qrySQL & " WHERE SuppID=" & rst!SuppID

    strSubject = "September 2012 Supplier's Listing"
    strMsgBody = "2008 Procedure Review Attached"
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Suppliers Confirmation forms", _
        acFormatHTML, strEmail, , , strSubject, strMsgBody, False

    ' move and loop
    rst.MoveNext
Loop

''Reset the query
qdf.SQL = qrySQL

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
dbs.Close
Set dbs = Nothing

PROC_Exit:
Exit Sub

PROC_ERR:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbOKOnly, _
          "Delivery Failure to the following email address: " & strEmail
    End If
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume PROC_Exit
```

Comment: I have implemented the code. Thank you very uch. The variable qdf is giving me an error. What should I declare it as?

Comment: Oops, that should be `Set qdf`, qdf can be declared as QueryDef (DAO)

Comment: Thank you so much. However the form sent does not have data with it. It has the labels with i.e address telephone fax email  and web no fields to go with it.

Comment: What is the name of the query that you based your report on? In the example it is called `Suppliers and Products`. The sql for this query is changed to only reference a particular supplier. Open the query and see if you get any results, if not, try changing the supplier ID to one that yoy know has results. If that works, change the first recordset to select only suppliers with results.

Comment: I did open the query and it has results and the report too.What surprises me is  when rechecked the query had changed and added WHERE SuppID=150; Now it was empty when I ran it. I have SuppID = 150. In fact SuppID starts from 1 to 197.

Comment: That is what the code does, it limits the query on which the report is based by SuppID. Does SupID 150 appear in the table `Products by Category`? Your query joins two tables using an INNER JOIN, so the ID must occur in both tables. I have modified the code slightly above.

Comment: Ok that's sorted now. The challenge now is the emailed report contains one record only. It contains the first entry only. Also there is a pop up window which tells me that Microsoft Outlook is send email allow , deny and help. I don't want that pop up.

Comment: At each loop, a report will be created for a supplier that has a record in [Suppliers and Products]. You said in a comment "There is a report which needs to be filtered. It has about 145 pages. this report has details for suppliers. each has to be sent to them.", so that is what you should get. The Outlook problem is a whole different ball game. You can consider sending the mail in a different way, such as SMTP, or else using Redemption.

Comment: Its working now. Thanks a lot. I added SQL code after the loop to reset the query. Will post the formatted code.

Comment: I have put the editted code that worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My boss wants me to use CDO. I am interested in sending the report as previous though this time the pop up from Outlook is bypassed.